# FFMPEG - watermark image

Tags: ffmpeg

i want to add watermark on some videos but problem is because image in some videos its too small and in some videos its too big, (i think it depends on input link resulution)

so all my videos have output '640:360' so how can i make watermark image to be same in all videos not on some videos smaller in some bigger

```
 ffmpeg -i "link" -i "/var/www/logo/logo1.png" -filter_complex 'overlay=10:10' -vcodec h264 -crf 25 -preset superfast -maxrate 600k -bufsize 600k -aspect '640:360' -s '640:360' ....
```

Answer (score 2):

Scale first then overlay:

```
ffmpeg -i "link" -i "/var/www/logo/logo1.png" -filter_complex '[0:v]scale=640:360[bg];[bg][1:v]overlay=10:10' -c:v libx264 -crf 25 -preset superfast -maxrate 600k -bufsize 600k output
```

Comment: That should be `640:360`

Comment: @Mulvya Typo fixed.